# Cannot remove PDB snapshot from CDB container

Tags: database, oracle, pdb, oracle18c

I'm using Oracle 18c with PDB technology. I have accidentically removed one of the .dbf datafiles from the file system. It's ok for me since I could recreate database by adding a new PDB snapshot. However, the old PDB is still visible under "mounted open read write" state and I basically cannot do anything with it:

1. I can't switch session/login to the corrupted PDB
2. I can't close it
3. I can't remove it by typing alter pluggable database
   xx... because it's still open.
4. I can't restore old datafiles - no backups are available.

Is there any option to force PDB to be removed in such state without shutting down whole container (CDB)?

Comment: You may try this: shutdown CDB, startup mount, alter all pdb datafiles offile, open the cdb, then drop the pdb. I cannot try these steps so not 100% sure they are enough

Comment: I could try setup similar config on a virtualmachine and test whether it works, and if so - do the same on the target environment. However, I thought there's easier option to remove something especially I have all of sysdba priviledges :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (successfully tested on 18.3 for a NOARCHIVELOG pdb after removing SYSTEM datafile):

```
alter session set container=cdb$root;
alter system set "_enable_pdb_close_noarchivelog"=true;
alter pluggable database MYPDB close abort;
drop pluggable database MYPDB including datafiles;
```

Comment: That's absolutely awsome! I was exactly  looking for that "_enable_pdb_close_noarchivelog" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! After changing "_enable_pdb_close_noarchivelog" to true it's possible to force shutdown PDB database even in corrupted state. It works perfect thanks guys for all your answers.

Comment: Keep in mind that `_enable_pdb_close_noarchivelog` is an undocumented parameter that in theory should only use in agreement with Oracle support. You should reset it with `alter system reset "_enable_pdb_close_noarchivelog" scope=both;`